# jQuery Click Event on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I'm having problems with the JQuery click event on Mobile. I've searched SO for answers and have found conflicting advice about the click event working in mobile browsers like Safari/Chrome.

Below is my Pen, it's a snippet of a much larger project. It's something I threw together in 5 minutes for the purpose of this post.

The JS is executed and the CSS class is toggled on desktop browsers, but not at all on mobile. What am I missing?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FknId

Thanks!

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn-navbar-responsive">Menu</a>
<ul class="navbar-menu navbar-hidden">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(".btn-navbar-responsive").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("navbar-hidden navbar-visible");
});
```

CSS

```
.btn-navbar-responsive {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    background-color: #50D78B;
 }


.navbar-visible {
    -webkit-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -webkit-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    -moz-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    ms-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    top: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-hidden {
    -webkit-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    transition: opacity, ease-in, 350ms;
    -webkit-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    -moz-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    -ms-transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    transition: top, ease-in, 350ms;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Please dont link to code, there is a syntax function for a reason.

Comment: My apologies, updating now.

Comment: I gotchu brah, just edited

Comment: What is it doing vs what do you expect it to do? You have not described the problem.

Comment: You should investigate the `touchstart` and `touchend` events for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to add the CSS property:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try event delegation with detection of touch event like this
//detect touch is supported or not

```
var event= ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? "touchstart" : "click";
```

//Delegate the proper event

```
$(".btn-navbar-responsive").on(event, function() {
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("navbar-hidden navbar-visible");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try .on() instead of the click() event.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(".btn-navbar-responsive").on('click', function() {
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("navbar-hidden navbar-visible");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't work. It works fine on desktop but not on Mobile Safari.